# Should my Wix installer use guids that are in my DLL?

Tags: dll, com, wix, registry, guid

Rolling out product for multiple languages and platforms? Not me. I just want to create a one-method DLL that returns "Hello World" and install it on my own computer, then communicate with it from Classic ASP or MS Access.

The code in the DLL is no problem. Discovering all relevant property sheets and filling them out correctly are. It's almost comical, after attempting an install, to see which property sheet values are used as file paths, which are in the registry, which are in the install/uninstall page, and so on. Who would expect the name of the INSTALL PROJECT to be used as the ACTUAL PRODUCT'S file path?

But today I limit my question to this: Should any GUID in my WiX project also be found in my DLL? My interface and class both have GUIDs. Do those need to be in the installer code, so the installer can add those to the registry? (Or are those GUIDs needed in the registry? If not there, then how are they used?)

Just trying to create a simple test to see WHAT WORKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have COM classes in your Dll that need registering then the general answer is to look at heat.exe, the WiX harvesting tool. For example the answer here:

[How to run heat.exe and register a dll in wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445322/how-to-run-heat-exe-and-register-a-dll-in-wix)

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/components-of-a-different-color/

Comment: I am trying the sample at https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/complus-applications/. Is says to add this: xmlns:complus=http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/ComPlusExtension. But it won't build. That schema URL is invalid.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, but it in trying to use it, these questions are raised: Is WiX stable? Is WiX viable? The example code seems outdated. The structure of a WiX document seems to have evolved considerably. I am trying to piece together a simple "hello, world" app that can be a COM server to unmanaged code (Classic ASP). No success so far.

Comment: WiX is used for several high profile Microsoft setups - it's fine. There's not enough detail in your post to be explicit. Is your COM Dll managed code? C++? You want COM+?  This does all work. The Firegiant tutorial and the wix-users mailing list should help.